VBA - HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell, line breaks in appear in different cells
I am not a VBA developer, however due to the nature of my issue, i need to turn to it.
Background, i am trying to download my data to excel. My DB raw data, contains HTML codes eg.
<h2>HTML Links</h2>
<p>HTML links are defined with the a tag:</p>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">This is a link</a>

I had somehow, thru the power of copying and pasting from the internet, almost achieve what i wanted. My main reference, is from this thread,
html-text-with-tags
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ie As Object
    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With Ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I9").Value
             'update to the cell that contains HTML you want converted
        .ExecWB 17, 0
             'Select all contents in browser
        .ExecWB 12, 2
             'Copy them
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2")
             'update to cell you want converted HTML pasted in
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

This is what happen when i execute the codes,

What i really want, is that the formatted text, will all appear in cell J2. I'm guessing it is because of the line breaks in the message in I9
What should i do?
Thank you.

"the formatted text, will all appear in cell J2" - you can't hyperlink only part of a cell's content: the link always applies to the whole text.
